# Calling a Closure from jenkins-library inside job's pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have jenkins_library with handleCheckout.groovy which handles checkout:

```
def handleCheckout = {
    if (env.gitlabMergeRequestId) {
        sh "echo 'Merge request detected. Merging...'"
        checkout([
                $class           : 'GitSCM',
                branches         : [[name: "${env.gitlabSourceNamespace}/${env.gitlabSourceBranch}"]],
                extensions       : [
                        [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
                        [$class: 'CleanCheckout'],
                        [
                                $class : 'PreBuildMerge',
                                options: [
                                        fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                                        mergeRemote    : env.gitlabTargetNamespace,
                                        mergeTarget    : env.gitlabTargetBranch
                                ]
                        ]
                ],
                userRemoteConfigs: [
                        [
                                credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID,
                                name         : env.gitlabTargetNamespace,
                                url          : env.gitlabTargetRepoSshURL
                        ],
                        [
                                credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID,
                                name         : env.gitlabSourceNamespace,
                                url          : env.gitlabSourceRepoSshURL
                        ]
                ]
        ])

    } else {
        sh "echo 'No merge request detected. Checking out current branch'"
        checkout([
                $class           : 'GitSCM',
                branches         : [[name: "${env.sourceBranch}"]],
                extensions       : [
                        [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
                        [$class: 'CleanCheckout']
                ],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID, url: env.GIT_URL]]
        ])
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call it from pipeline after imporing jenkins-library like that:

```
@Library('jenkins-util-lib') _

 stage('prepare') {
            sh "env | sort"
            handleCheckout()
```

It ends with error:

```
No signature of method: handleCheckout.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Works well while method is declared and called inside the pipeline.

Comment: Is this method located inside your global vars (`/vars`) or your core library package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please your setup

1) handleCheckout.groovy must be located in `vars` folder (has to check)
2) handleCheckout.groovy  must have `def call` (you have to change)
3) Inside your pipeline you have to run Jenkinsfilename(), in your case `handleCheckout`

Just in case doc - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

So at the and you have to change procedure name to `def call` and check Jenkins file location (must be in vars folder inside shared library)

Comment: 1) Was there already
2) Did the trick

I wasn't aware procedure needs to have `def call` to be called from pipeline.

Works like a charm now, thanks.

Comment: Jenkins creates an object handleCheckout based on the file name of your groovy file under /vars. In your original syntax, you defined handleCheckout as a property of the object handleCheckout. You should see the def call() ... a bit like the constructor of this object. It supports the use of handleCheckout as a build step in declarative syntax.